How can I stop pymupdf converting 'ff' to a different character such as @ or I?
I'm reading in text from a bunch of PDFs using the following code:
import fitz
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# open the document
doc = fitz.open(filename_path)

# get the text from each page in the document
for idx, page in enumerate(doc):
    page = doc.load_page(idx)
    page_text = page.get_text("text")
    doc_text = doc_text + page_text

# store the document text in a "text" column in my dataframe
doc_df["text"] = doc_text

It mostly works fine but I've noticed that words containing 'ff' such as 'stuff' are not read in correctly e.g. 'stu@' or 'stuI'. From a brief search it seems this is something to do with 'ligatures' but I don't know what they are or how to resolve it.
Example text similar to what I read in from my PDF:
"I found some stuff in the bag"
Text after pymupdf has read it in:
"I found some stuI in the bag"
It doesn't seem to be a static conversion either as once it converted ff to @ (in a different word but same phrase as above used below for illustration):
"I found some stu@ in the bag"
What should the corrected code look like so I can stop this happening?

You can adjust the text extraction flags such that ligatures are decomposed. The simplest form is using flags=0. On another note. with latest version, using parameter sort_True will establish natural reading sequence in addition. So I recommend .get_text(flags=0, sort=True). This also works with an additional clip=rect, where rectis any rectangle on the page. Happy coding!

Thanks for replying Jorj but that didn't work. I tried
page.get_text("text", flags=0)
page.get_text(flags=0)
page.get_text("text", flags=0)
page.get_text(flags=0, sort=True)
page.get_text("text", flags=0, sort=True)
...and I get the same result and same character conversion issue with all of them :(
Do I need to do something in doc.load_page()?

No - better submit an issue or a Discussions item on the GitHub repo.

If your PDF does not have proper To Unicode mappings or equivalent information in its fonts, those ligatures may present themselves as "@" or some other special character to text extractors.

Thanks @mkl. How do I check/change that? I converted Word documents to PDFs by saving as PDF. Is there a better way? I used the new Aptos font. Could changing to an older font like Times New Roman or Arial help? Sorry if these are stupid questions.

Actually I'm more used to old software creating such improper mappings, not current MS Word versions. Can you share an example document to analyze?

In general, I found that LibreOffice does a much better job in converting (exporting!) MS Office to PDF than the in-built app functions.
